# Comparing values in Excel cells

Tags: python, excel

I have two workbooks:

- wkbk1 has a single IP address in each cell of a specific column.
- wkbk2 has either no IP address, a single IP, or multiple IP's that
  are separated by a new line (vs a comma) in each cell of a specific
  column.

I am trying to compare the value of cell in wkbk1 to the values in wkbk2.

The problem I am having is that the search will compare a wkbk1 IP = 10.10.10.16 as equal to wkbk2 IP = 10.10.10.168 (and any other variant).

If I search by (wkbk1 IP + \n), it fails to compare single line cells.

The following is my code:

```
#variable top store the highest row number
mRow = str(mapIP.get_highest_row()) 
eRow = str(assetSheet.get_highest_row())

i = 2 #variable for row number output, skips the first row (b/c it is the header row, duh)

#create data by comparing IP in map to IP in CMDB
for mapIpRow in mapIP['A1':'A' + mRow]:
        for mapIpCell in mapIpRow:
            for assetIpRow in assetSheet['E1':'E' + eRow]:
                for assetIpCell in assetIpRow:
                    assetIp = str(assetIpCell.value)
                    mapIp = str(mapIpCell.value)
                    if mapIp in assetIp:
                        outSheet['A' + str(i)].value = mapIp
                        print(mapIp) #just for feedback that the program is running
                        dnsM = mapIP['B' + str(mapIpCell.row)].value
                        owner = assetSheet['F' + str(assetIpCell.row)].value
                        dnsQ = assetSheet['B' + str(assetIpCell.row)].value #cishort
                        dnsQ2 = assetSheet['C' + str(assetIpCell.row)].value #cialias
                        dnsQ3 = assetSheet['D' + str(assetIpCell.row)].value #ciDesc
                        ciIP = assetSheet['E' + str(assetIpCell.row)].value #ciIP
                        ciID = assetSheet['A' + str(assetIpCell.row)].value #ciID
                        outSheet['B' + str(i)].value = dnsM
                        outSheet['C' + str(i)].value = owner
                        outSheet['D' + str(i)].value = dnsQ
                        outSheet['E' + str(i)].value = dnsQ2
                        outSheet['F' + str(i)].value = dnsQ3
                        outSheet['G' + str(i)].value = ciIP
                        outSheet['H' + str(i)].value = ciID
                        print owner #just for feedback that the program is running
                        i = i + 1
                    else:
                        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take each cell value (which may contain 0, 1, or multiple IPs) and put it into a list using `.split('\n')`.  Your list comparison `if mapIp in assetIp` should still work.

```
assetIp = assetIpCell.value.split('\n') if assetIpCell.value else ''
mapIp = str(mapIpCell.value)
if mapIp in assetIp:
```

This should resolve your problem:

> The problem I am having is that the search will compare a wkbk1 IP = 10.10.10.16 as equal to wkbk2 IP = 10.10.10.168 (and any other variant).

The `in` operator when comparing strings will return substring results, i.e.:

```
'a' in 'David' == True
'10.10.10.16` in `10.10.10.168` == True
```

The `in` operator when used with a list will return `True` only if an exact match exists in the list;

```
'10.10.10.16`' in ['10.52.1.1', '99.32.9.0', '168.152.1.1', `10.10.10.168`] == False
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I did have to convert assetIpCell.value to a string, then split into a list.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Cheers. Do consider marking this answer as "accepted" if it's solved the problem. Out of curiosity, what `type` of data was in the `assetIpCell.value` to begin with? I would expect it to be string (but I did not test)

Comment: It is a cell of IP addresses, they are separated by a carriage return instead of a comma. But some of the cells are empty, and they would be assigned a Nonetype

Comment: Ahhh OK I understand the `None` type was throwing an exception hence the `str` conversion.  If you want to avoid the `str` conversion, you could use a ternary statment: `assetIp = assetIpCell.value.split('\n') if assetIpCell.value else ''`