# Compare excel sheets by scanning the second sheet

Tags: python

I need to compare excel sheets, the script will see the first data on Sheet1 then will scan the Sheet2 for the same data, if no identical it will be printed out, then move to the next cell of Sheet1 it will scan again the Sheet2 for idetical data and so on..., I have the idea but I don't know how to start this using python language.

Comment: Have a look to [xlrd package](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd)

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113173/compare-2-excel-files-using-python

Comment: How big is your file? Approach you mentioned may not be optimal for large files.