# How to compare 2 different excel files of same name in 2 different folder?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of excel sheet in one folder and another set in folder 2. If the same file name in both folders matches I need to take the difference in the cell.

The difference in column I have a script below. How to pass for loop for this?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel('firstfolder/0.xls')
df2 = pd.read_excel('secondfolder/0.xls')
difference = df1[df1!=df2]
print (difference)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your folders contain the same xls files, and the file all have the same structure, then you can use `glob` and iterate -

```
import glob

diffs = []
for i, j in zip(*map(glob.glob, ['firstfolder/*.xls', 'secondfolder/*.xls'])):
    i, j = map(pd.read_excel, [i, j])
    diffs.append(i[i != j])

diff = pd.concat(diffs, axis=0)
```

Comment: This code is really elegant. Great use of the map function.

Answer (score 0):

### courtesy : [Compare 2 excel files using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113173/compare-2-excel-files-using-python/37113788)

```
from itertools import zip_longest
import xlrd
import os

first_files = os.listdir('folder1')
second_files = os.listdir('folder2')
matches = [x for x in second_files if x in first_files]
#print(matches)

for (matches[0]) in matches:
    print (matches[0])
    rb1 = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join('folder1',matches[0]))
    rb2 = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join('folder2',matches[0]))
    sheet1 = rb1.sheet_by_index(0)
    sheet2 = rb2.sheet_by_index(0)

    for rownum in range(max(sheet1.nrows, sheet2.nrows)):
        if rownum < sheet1.nrows:
            row_rb1 = sheet1.row_values(rownum)
            row_rb2 = sheet2.row_values(rownum)
        
            for colnum, (c1, c2) in enumerate(zip_longest(row_rb1, row_rb2)):
                if c1 != c2:
                    print ("Row {} Col {} - {} != {}".format(rownum+1, colnum+1, c1, c2))
            
        else:
            print ("Row {} missing".format(rownum+1))
```

Comment: You asked for a pandas answer, but I don't see pandas being used here? Did you look at my answer? It's a lot simpler than this.