# How do I compare adjacent cells in excel using Python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have two columns and I am trying to return the total count of rows where both adjacent cells within the two columns are identical. I am trying to iterate through each row of two columns and compare each item in the first column with its adjacent item in the second column
i.e.

`A | B`
`1 | 1`
`2 | 3`
`4 | 4`

returns 2 for there are 2 pairs that are identical.

My two columns are Q and R, so far:

```
import openpyxl

excel_document = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')


sheet = excel_document.get_sheet_by_name('Page 1')
created_closed = sheet['Q2':'R1844']
count = 0

for cell in column:
    if Q[2] == R[2]: #something along the lines of this
          count += 1
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: What have you tried? Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37113173/4650297) help?

Comment: You need to compare cell values.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx')
df = df[df['A'] == df['B']]
print (df.shape[0])
```

Comment: Can you add some commentary? I know it's a short few lines, but can you clarify? I assume the `df[df['A'] == df['B']]` compares each cell within both columns, row by row, and if they're equal...? What's the `df.shape[0]` do?

Answer (score 1):

The answer that comes to mind is:

`count = created_closed[created_closed['Q']==created_closed['R']].shape[0]`

No `for` loop required because pandas takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

A - Try using `numpy` and `pandas`.

1- Find all intersections: This will return an array with the elements that were common in both columns

```
from pandas import read_excel
import numpy as np

df = read_excel('excel_data.xlsx', names=['A','B'], header=None)
np.intersect1d(df['A'], df['B'])
```

2- now count the length of the array

B- read each `column` and save to, two separate `dictionary` with `key` being `position` and `value` being the `value` at that `position`. Compare the two `dictionaries` and keep track of matches.

something like this, I am traveling right now so I can no test.

```
count = 0
col1 = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
col2= {1:'g', 2:'b', 3:'v'}

for key in col1.keys():
    if col1[key] == col2[key]:
        count = count + 1
```