# Compare two columns in sheet with Python and print matches

Tags: python

I have a group of keywords in two different columns in a Google Sheets. How do I compare and print the matches:

Example:

```
Column A 
Row 1 Hi
Row 2 Hallo
Row 3 Bye

Column B
Row 1 Hi
Row 2 No
Row 3 Hallo
```

Print:

```
Hi
Hallo
```

Or is it possible directly in sheets? Thanks! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare 2 excel files using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113173/compare-2-excel-files-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
# read column1 to list_1. there are some libs could help you.
list_1 = []
# read column2 to list_2
list_2 = []

# calc the result from list_1 and list_2
res = [x for x in list_1 for y in list_2 if x == y]
print(res)
```

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this 
code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you can save your file in .csv format, you can use `pandas` library.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')

column_1_values = set(df['A'].unique())
column_2_values = set(df['B'].unique())
matches = column_1_values.intersection(column_2_values)

print('\n'.join(map(str, matches)))
```

Comment: I'll try your solution, Maria! :) Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it all in Google Sheets. Suppose that the first set of values is in column A and the second set of values is in column B. Then:

1. In a new column, paste and drag this formula: `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B1,A:A,0)),"Not found","Found")`.
2. Sort the new column, and manually copy the range of values in column B that are adjacent to "Found" in the new column.

There are also other ways to do it in Google Sheets, this is just one of them.